# How to connect multiple salesforce org each other

Tags: integration

I have  multiple org approx 50 org.
Now my requirement is below.

I have a "client" object with multiple record in each org,
Now i want to search a record from all org from my source org(Source org may be any one org with in 50 org).

How i archive above scenario in salesforce.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are these orgs connected via salesforce-to-salesforce? or are they standalone orgs?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 50 org API connectivity is going to create data issue
Salesforce to Saleasorce use pub/sub configuring 50 connection is cumbersome. 
A middle layer will be a good integration approach. This requirement is unique.

Comment: I think a middle layer interfacing with a data warehouse that regularly coalesces the 50 orgs is the best bet. Then you just call out to the app and it will search the one DB rather than 50 individual DBs. Even if 50 db's could be achieved, it would be extraordinarily slow.

Answer (score 0):

Start Here for details on configuring Salesforce-to-Salesforce:  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce

Comment: Salesforce to Salesforce won't allow him to search another org for data. It only allows each org to share records with other orgs in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to use the Salesforce REST APIs to search for the records from the 50 orgs, and quite possibly from another client that is not in Salesforce. ( Since you can't make more than 10 api calls in one transaction. )

You might look to develop some Java desktop client or some web application that makes calls to the 50 orgs and lists the results along with the Org that it was found in.

Hope that gives you some idea on how to get started.

Documentation on the Salesforce REST API
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_rest.pdf

Comment: I think  we can make 100 call out in one transaction.

Comment: Yes you are right. Didn't know that this limit had been increased. Thanks!